# System.LimitException: DML currently not allowed

Tags: force.com

When i am adding header component to new visual force page then it is returning exception saying

```
Visualforce Error

System.LimitException: DML currently not allowed

Class.ExceptionManager.save: line 14, column 1
Class.ExceptionService.saveException: line 25, column 1
Class.BaseController.<init>: line 348, column 1
Class.SignUpController.<init>: line 79, column 1
```

How do i get a solution for this problem ?

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" controller="RequestTradeController" standardStylesheets="false" >
    <script>
        document.title = '{!$Label.lblCR} - New Trade Relationship';
    </script> 
    <c:CommonComponent />
    <apex:form >
        <h2>Request New Trade Relationship</h2>

        <table width="70%">
            <tr><td><apex:pageMessage severity="warning">Select how you would like to send your request.</apex:pageMessage>    </td></tr>
            <tr><td align="center" class="button_link bgcolor-tab"><apex:commandButton styleClass="button_style button_link" action="{!test}" value="Request New Relationship using the Seller's CashRelease ID" id="theButton1"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="center"><b>OR</b></td></tr>
            <tr><td align="center" class="button_link bgcolor-tab"><apex:commandButton styleClass="button_style button_link" action="{!redirectToNewTrade}" value="Request New Relationship by Sending an Email Invitation to the Seller" id="theButton2"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

In this  is already allowing the DML. so why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to set the allowDML attribute of your component to true for DML to be allowed by your component.  Take a look at the documentation on [apex:component](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_component.htm).

For example:

**Component**

```
<apex:component controller="MyComponentController" allowDML="true">
  <apex:form>
      <apex:commandButton value="Execute DML" action="{!executeDML}"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

**Component Controller**

```
public with sharing class MyComponentController {

     public PageReference executeDML() {
         Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test');
         insert a;

         return null;
     }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page >
    <c:myComponent />
</apex:page>
```

From the [apex:component documentation on allowDML](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_component.htm):

> If this attribute is set to "true", you can include DML within the
>   component. The default is "false". Allowing DML can cause side-effects
>   that could be problematic for consumers using the component with
>   partial page updates. When allowing DML within a component, you should
>   include rerender attributes so the consumer can appropriately refresh
>   their page. In addition, you should detail, in the description of the
>   component, what data is manipulated by the DML so that consumers of
>   the component are aware of potential side-effects.

It is also possible that the error is being caused because there is DML in a constructor which is not allowed.

It appears that the Exception is originating in your SignUpController (Class.SignUpController.: line 79, column 1) which is not the page's controller.  I'd start with looking at that.

Comment: please see the code, then tell me why i getting this error?

Comment: Thanks for posting some of your code.  I updated my answer with another possibility and a suggestion.